# Build prism custom nuget packages

Tags: prism

**Can I build a custom nuget packages of the prism library to use it in my application ?**

**When I change the "Solution Configuration" to Release-Signed and try to compile I get this errors:**

Error       Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "..\prism.pfx". Could not find file 'F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\prism.pfx'.   Prism
Error       Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "....\prism.pfx". Could not find file 'F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\prism.pfx'.    Prism.Wpf
Error       Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "....\prism.pfx". Could not find file 'F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\prism.pfx'.    Prism.Mef.Wpf
Error       Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "....\prism.pfx". Could not find file 'F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\prism.pfx'.    Prism.Autofac.Wpf
Error       Metadata file 'F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\Prism\bin\Release-Signed\Prism.dll' could not be found  Prism.Forms F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\CSC

......
......
......

Error       Metadata file 'F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\Wpf\Prism.Wpf\bin\Release-Signed\Prism.Wpf.dll' could not be found  Prism.Wpf.Tests F:\repos\github\Prism\Source\Wpf\Prism.Wpf.Tests\CSC

**Can any one guide me to do this ? I am a beginner to this:)**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't build the Release-Signed configuration because you don't have access to the key.  You would want to build using the Release configuration.  Just curious, why do you want to use a custom build of Prism and not the official packages?

Comment: thanks @Brian, No I use the official packages but, correct me if I wrong, I saw that the PopupWindow has some limitations, there is no cancel button, default button, icons, for that reason I build my custom confirmation class to support this, just for curiosity and just for knowing how things works :) I am a beginner

Comment: The default Prism has two default popup windows that do contain ok, cancel buttons with the proper default buttons set.  Now, they don't have icons.  Having said that, you don't need to recompile and repackage the entire Prism source code just to use your custom popup window.  You can easily add your custom popup window in your specific project and extend Prims to use that instead.

Comment: sorry I mean the three buttons Yes,No,Cancel all together, this is not supported by prism popup window. I'll use what you suggest. Thank you for your time.